# Python3 - Combine Dictionaries with existing key value pairs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

So... I know we can combine 2 dictionaries from python 3.5 like so:

```
z = {**x,**y}                  # x,y are 2 similar dictionaries, with nested entries
```

But in this method, any conflicting key,value pairs in 'x' is replaced with the ones in 'y'.

I want the conflicting key,value pairs to contain largest data present in x or y.

For example:

```
x = {1:'small_data',2:{1:'random laaaarge data',2:'random small data'}}
y = {1:'laaaaaarge_data',2:{1:'random small data',2:'random laaaarge data'}}
```

Now

```
z = {**x,**y}
# DATA in z should be {1:'laaaaaarge_data',2:{1:'random laaaarge data',2:'random laaaarge data'}}
```

***NOTE***: It should work for any arbitrary data that has a size.

Is this even possible? If so, what is the most pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
def merge_dicts(dict_list):
    merged = {}
    for sub_dict in dict_list:
        for key, value in sub_dict.items():
            if key in merged:
                merged[key] = get_biggest(merged[key], value)
            else:
                merged[key] = value
    return merged

def get_biggest(*items):
    # function for comparing your 2 items based on your "size" requirements
    return biggest
```

Comment: This wont work for complex dictionaries that have nested dictionaries as values.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your use-case, then. You can make your comparison function arbitrarily complex. If that's the issue you're attempting to resolve, you would need to edit your question to reflect that.